# Import Sheet Data and Sum Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import the data from one sheet to another then paste the sheet 1 value against sheet 2 with the sum of both the value.

Below is my script and which import the value with the sum, however, I am not able to paste the data against  in destination value  .

If you  refer my sample sheet you will get more clarity. I am trying to create something like "vlookup with Sum function"

If "sheet1!A:A" data exists, then sheet 1 value should paste against Sheet 2 cell value   A:B

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uFucL-R5CvT48XH0PX9WF3glTG4yIaCPY7YrxwZSJ1U/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i = 2; i < 6; i++) { 
    var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    var sheetTwo = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  
    var Nameone = sheetOne.getRange(i, 1).getValue()
    var Nametwo = sheetTwo.getRange(i, 1).getValue()
    var values = sheetOne.getDataRange().getValues();

    Logger.log(values)
    // if( values[i][0] == Nametwo  && Nameone == Nametwo)
    if(values[1][0] == Nametwo || values[2][0] == Nametwo || values[3][0] == Nametwo && Nameone == Nametwo) {
      var sheetoneData = sheetOne.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var sheetTwoData = sheetTwo.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var Masterdata = sheetTwo.getRange(i, 2).setValue(sheetoneData + sheetTwoData);
    } else {
      var sheetTwoData = sheetTwo.getRange(i, 2).setValue(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a sufficient problem description

Comment: Edit the question

Comment: You still do not indicate what happens, what you expect to happen, the errors you receive, or what you have done to try to resolve your issue.

Comment: The script is not validating the value of sheet 1 if I change the sheet 1 order , example Sheet 1 - A row consists of A, B, C ,D 
and sheet 2 A row A, B, D, C.
Script printing the value of Sheet 1 order it doesn't search or validate Sheet 2 A Row Content 
I

Comment: your question needs to convey this information in a nicely formatted example. Comments do not convey data well. In your question, show the starting configuration, what you want, and what your current code yields when run.

Comment: Also note that you have a malformed condition for your if statement. When combining `||` and `&&` conditions, it is **very strongly recommended** to use parentheses to group conditions. Bad: `if(a==1 || b==2 && c==3)` Good: `if((a==1 || b==2) && c==3)` Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got the right element id? I'm assuming sheet one is at the first position, in which case you'd want `.getRange(i, 0)`.

Comment: Hi I am not  able  to  paste the  sheet 1  value in sheet 2 if I change the cell orders

Comment: Did you also update the element in the for loop? `for (var i=1..)`. Also what results do you get when you run the debugger?

Comment: The script not getting the value of C ,D from the sheet 1, it pasted 0

Comment: Well based on this line, you are explicitly setting the value to zero: `var sheetTwoData = sheetTwo.getRange(i,2).setValue(0);`

Comment: I recommend refactoring your if statement as it's too many conditions inside 1 if-block. It's hard to know what it's actually returning when you have it searching for 3-4 different scenarios at once. Additionally, I would still like to know what happens when you run the debugger.

Comment: While debugger i am not getting any error _i think i need to spit the scenarios suing if the method